# How many languages are described by a regular expression?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

How many languages can a Regular Expression describe is it only one or infinite?
I have tried to google it but i haven't found any answer?

I know that a Regular Expression describes a Regular Language?

Comment: One language, though there might be infinitely many strings described by a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of regular expressions (they are usually defined in parallel to the language denoted) you see there is only one language denoted by a given expression. That language could be empty, finite or infinite, but that is another question.

Answer (score 3):

Every regular expression describes one language --- the language of words matched by the regular expression, or, in other words, the language of words accepted by the finite automaton corresponding to the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

A language is described by a regular expression if and only if it is regular.

There are infinitely many regular languages over any fixed alphabet.